# Magento2 validate billing & shipping address before place order

Tags: magento2, validation

How can I validate billing & shipping address form before place order. I have a payment method before place order I want to validate it. using js. Just like submit it form to display required validation

Answer (score 0):

Magento has it covered already: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html